# Is there a Ruby-Way™ to handle this kind of loop?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, loops

I am trying print section titles for grouped elements in a flat array. I would only like the section title to appear *once* per group.

The example below works, but it feels pretty inelegant for Ruby. I'm certain there must be a better way to do this ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
foo = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]

i = 0;

f = foo[i]
comp = f

while(i < foo.count) do
  puts "Section #{f}";

  while(f == comp) do
    puts f
    i += 1
    f = foo[i]
  end

  comp = f
end
```

---

Desired output

```
Section 1
1
1
1
1
Section 2
2
2
2
Section 3
3
3
```

---

I was hoping there was some kind of `Array#current` or `Array#next` instance methods, but it looks like Ruby Array objects don't keep an internal iterator.

Comment: You can get iterator by calling `foo.to_enum`. It has `next` method.

Comment: @Mladen, very cool. Thank you <3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foo.group_by{|e| e }.each do |header, group| 
  puts "Section #{header}"
  puts group.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: This is awesome! I understand it involves iterating through the array more than once, but that's very elegant :)

Comment: Since `group_by` accepts a block, it works really well for more complex data structures.

Comment: yes, this is perfect. I will be grouping items based on date, and the block will make it very easy to accomplish that. Thanks again.

Comment: well, to be strict, given the input shown (repeated elements are consecutive), it would be more efficent Enumerable#chunk (Ruby 1.9)

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
j = 0
foo.each  do |i|
  unless j == i
    puts "Section #{i}"
    j = i
  end
  puts i
end
```

Comment: Hmm, I like the use of `Array#each` here. This also only requires one pass through the array. Thanks for the help :)